# Code in "catch" block of try-catch doesn't execute

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a block of code that almost always throws a `DivideByZero` Exception. So I put it in a `try` block along with `catch (DivideByZeroException)` with a bit of code within `catch` to run to deal with the error.

```
try 
{
    //code that throws exception
}
catch (DivideByZeroException)
{
    //misc code to run
    test = 235;
}
```

After running the code and debugging, `test` is never 235. Am I doing this wrong and/or is there another way? How do I make a piece of code run within the catch block after the exception is caught?

Comment: If line is not executing then there is something else going on. Either the DivideByZeroException is not being thrown, the try/catch is in the wrong place, or you're rechanging the value of `test` outside the catch.

Comment: Just checked, and you are correct. When evaluating x/(x^2 - 5), I would expect the exception to be thrown at x=sqrt(5), but since I'm not using a high enough accuracy, it never happens and passes over that value